# Learning to draw manga

Tags: drawing

I do not know how to draw, but I really want to create my own manga.
Please tell me if the following approach is acceptable:

1. Create a simple storyboard.
2. Gradually master the drawing skills, based on those drawings that
   are presented in the storyboard.
3. Gradually draw a manga on the storyboard

Comment: A question that can be answered by an entire book or library of books is too broad for stackexchange. I think one of the books you're looking for is [Scott McCloud's _Making Comics_](http://scottmccloud.com/2-print/3-mc/index.html), another might be [Will Eisner's _Comics and Sequential Art_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comics_and_Sequential_Art).

Comment: This IS pretty broad! If you have any narrower questions as you start learning how to draw manga (style, etc.) please do ask them :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of books on this subject matter. Check out your local library or online/brick and mortar book sellers.

Some I would recommend are:

1. [Making Comics: Storytelling Secrets of Comics, Manga and Graphic Novels by Scott McCloud](https://www.amazon.in/Making-Comics-Storytelling-Secrets-Graphic/dp/0060780940/ref=sr_1_4?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1529327679&sr=1-4&keywords=scott%20mccloud)
2. [Shoujo Manga Techniques: Writing Stories by Mako Itsuki](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/156970970X)

There are also plenty of how to tutorials on youtube and on various blogs around the Internet to check as well. Check a few different sources so you vary the information you pick; it's not good to only go to one source for information.

If there are any artists you like (on deviantart, tumblr, web comic artists or actual published artists) feel free to reach out and contact them. I'm sure they'd be happy to share their techniques.

---

Other things to think about:

- How are you going to circulate your story? Do you plan on selling hard copies or distribute as a web comic? Or is it just for your entertainment?
- You will need to learn how to draw not just people but objects, environments, perspective and proportions. Optional things to learn are coloring, screen toning, shading, animals and chibi style
- Some people recommend drawing daily / frequently just to improve your skill. Like any other skill, the more you do it, the better you get.
- Other artists recommend learning to draw realistically / using a realistic style first, and then stylize. Others say to just continue practicing your style until it develops/solidifies. Pick whichever is best for you.

Good luck and happy drawing!

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed answer.
Tell me, please, given your recommendations, is it worth using the approach presented in my question?

It is difficult to study immensity. So, skills will be formed within the task).

Comment: I would say your technique is *almost* complete. Make sure you have some idea of a story (or maybe overarching theme if you are doing more of a "slice of life" style manga) and once you have that solidified, begin story boarding. The storyboarding helps with how you want to pose characters, speech bubbles and environment. Then once you have a nearly complete story board, you can start adding actual art and text, using the storyboard as a guide. So to sum up steps are: (1) consider story or theme (2) story board (3) apply drawing skills to story board (4) write the complete manga.